# Redirect blog page to latest post?

Tags: redirect, post-meta

How can I make it so when the blog link in the nav bar is clicked it redirects to the most recent post?

I know how to display just the latest post on the blog page, but I want it to actually redirect to the post page itself as I'm displaying a full screen background image called in via a custom metabox on each post page.

Is there perhaps a PHP query and redirect function I can apply to the blog page template, or is there a better way?

UPDATE: the following redirect script works great but I just need a way to get the URL of the latest post:

```
$URL = "http://www.google.com";
wp_redirect( $URL, 301 ); 
exit;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the get_posts() function:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Redirect
*/

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'post_type' => 'post'
);
$post = get_posts($args);
if($post){
    $url = get_permalink($post[0]->ID);
    wp_redirect( $url, 301 ); 
    exit;
}
```

Comment: thank you but unfortunately i can't get this to work.  I have put it in a new template file and then assigned my 'blog' page to use that template - is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi Brian. I'm now trying to do the same thing with categories. Do you happen to know how I can do this?  My question is here. Thank you - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29456/display-most-recent-post-in-category-instead-of-archive

Comment: Hi Brian, this was working fine until I changed my permalink structure. Any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: I might be overthinking things but for this use case is a 301 appropriate? Given that the latest post might change regularly isn't it by definition a temporary redirect? Especially as you may still want Google to index the posts page itself, not the redirect destination. (genuine question, I have no idea)